# Python-Flask: Pass data to machine learning python script and get results back

Tags: python, flask

My knowledge in web frameworks are pretty bad. I have a build a machine learning model in python and it takes a set of strings as an input and return results. After searching on the web I came across with `Flask`. But what I don't know is how to actually create a flask app to actually take a string and allow user to submit and pass that string to my machine learning python script and return results. This is all I have so far

```
import threading
import subprocess
import os
import sys
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, abort
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

def run_script():
    theproc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "ML_script.py"])
    theproc.communicate()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

If you can point to an example or provide a solution /skeleton that would be fantastic.

Comment: Why use `subprocess` at all? Just import your functions and use them like you normally would any other function. DISCLAIMER: I don't know how computationally intense your functions are and this might make your server hang but the answer to that problem is a different question.

Comment: It is bit computation intense take about 1 minute to calculate everything but I want to show something like "processing" until results come back.. not sure why I use subprocess... it was in flask website.

Comment: I have done this exact thing before and the way I did it was create two applications. one front end that took the data form the user and passed it to the other one (on a larger faster AWS instance) via JSON and got the results back the same way. You can of course do this all on one server and load a spinner/loading animation and then replace it it with content when you get a reply.

Comment: Any chance you can direct me towards more complete example..? Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use your machine learning functions like any other Python function there is no need for `subprocess`. Setup your app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, abort, jsonify, request,redirect, json
from my_app.machine_learning import analyzer
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/learning', methods=['POST'])
def learning():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    # data == {"userInput": "whatever text you entered"}
    response = analyzer(data)
    return jsonify(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I used a stand in name for your machine learning module but `analyzer()` should be a function in that module that calls all your other functions needed to do your computations and returns a dictionary that has your results in it. So something like this:

```
def analyzer(data):
    vocab = build_vocab(training_data)
    cl = train_classifier(vocab, trianing_data)
    results = cl.predict(data)
    results = format_results_to_dict()
    return results
```

The template is pretty straight forward:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/script.js"></script>
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Calculation</h1>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
    <input id="user-input" placeholder="Text to be analyzed"></input>
    <p id="results">Results will go here<p>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And the JS script to tie it all together:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(event){
        var uInput = $("#user-input").val();
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '/learning',
              data: JSON.stringify({userInput: uInput}),
              contentType: 'application/json',
              success: function(response){
                   $("#results").text(response.results);
                },
          });
    });
});
```

Comment: this is really fantastic

Comment: *blushes*. If you want to see the implementation I was talking about in my earlier commetns you can check it out [here](https://github.com/im-auld/tweetTrack). Be warned, there is no documentation and little in the way of comments. It was done in a 4 day sprint as part of a project for a class so getting it working and deployed took precedence.

Comment: Thanks again. I will definitely look at it.