# Passing data to Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have built a machine learning model and pickled the model. Now I want to pass a JSON string to the model and have it output a response based on the trained model. I have Flask up and running and Im using the following code base as a reference:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import pandas as pd
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
     json_ = request.json
     query_df = pd.DataFrame(json_)
     query = pd.get_dummies(query_df)
     prediction = clf.predict(query)
     return jsonify({'prediction': list(prediction)})
if __name__ == '__main__':
     clf = joblib.load('model.pkl')
     app.run(port=8080)
```

How can I pass a JSON string to the predict page that is referenced in Flask and how do I get output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be of some use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704411/python-flask-pass-data-to-machine-learning-python-script-and-get-results-back/31706842#31706842

Comment: indeed it does - many thanks